# Best way to have an Android app poll periodically in the background

Tags: android

Take the Gmail app as an example.  Whether the phone is on or not, it polls every 10 minutes or so to download new emails which may have arrived since you last checked.

I know how to create a new service and bind to it.  But I can see a few ways to accomplish this:

- Bind once, and have the service run in an infinite loop, sleeping for 10 minutes between each loop
- Bind and unbind right when it's done, scheduling the next bind somehow in 10 minutes
- Using the AlarmManager class to schedule future polls

What are the trade offs?   How does the Gmail app accomplish it?

Thanks!

Comment: Doesn't Gmail use Android Cloud To Device? I would guess so... but this is a wild guess without any concrete knowledge. http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/05/android-cloud-to-device-messaging.html

Comment: @NeTeInStEiN looks like it does, I was mistaken

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Gmail app uses pushing, not polling. I suggest using this technique instead, polling is a battery killer in mobile devices.

To implement pushing, take a look at [C2DM](http://code.google.com/android/c2dm/index.html).

If you still want to poll, the recommended way would be to set up a periodic alarm in the AlarmManager.

**UPDATE**: Google has deprecated C2DM and replaced it with [Google Cloud Messaging (GCM)](http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/index.html)

**UPDATE**: Google has deprecated GCM and replaced it with 
[Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM)](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/)

Comment: Or, consider Urban Airship or Xtify as commercial services offering similar solutions to C2DM.

Comment: @CommonsWare One thing to note is that if everyone implements their own pushing service, then the whole point is lost. I think we should stick to C2DM whether we it like it or not.

Comment: "One thing to note is that if everyone implements their own pushing service, then the whole point is lost." -- you are welcome to your opinion. C2DM is a Google Labs beta project and therefore may lack the support and service level guarantees that some companies may wish.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the comments all!  Loving the quick responses.  In my app there is no unique data per user, each phone is polling to see if some universal info has changed.  So not sure if push per device is the right solution here.  The AlarmManager looks great.  Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

- For a continuous, but not intensive poll like the one you comment (in the range of minutes between polls), I would implement it with AlarmManager. That way you make sure the phone wakes up to poll without the need for a wakelock, which would destroy your battery. As CommonsWare pointed out, you will still need to implement a wakelock for the time your code is executing, but you can release it as soon as the code is done, avoiding keeping the phone on while just waiting. See his comment for an example on how to implement it.
- I would use a Service if, instead, you need faster polls during a shorter period of time (seconds between each poll), since setting alarms does not make sense to such short periods, and the battery would drain anyway.

Comment: You still need a `WakeLock` if the work you will do takes a material amount of time, as the alarm-invoked `BroadcastReceiver` cannot do much in `onReceive()`. See the `WakefulIntentService` for one wrapper around the `WakeLock` work: https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-wakeful

Comment: @CommonsWare you're right, but the point I wanted to make is that you do not need to keep the phone on when doing *nothing*. BTW, that's a great demo. I will study it in detail.

Comment: Oh, I agree completely -- an everlasting service just to watch the clock tick is an anti-pattern. I was just quibbling a bit on the "without the need for a wakelock" part, that's all.

Comment: @Aleadam : I have scheduled an alarm to be executed every 1 minute. The tas is to poll a server. It works if I fine when I am not doing any intensive task on the phone. But If I start Playing any game, the polling stops(the alarms stops I guess). What is the solution for this?