# Toast Stop - getConnectedNodes

Tags: java, android

I made a service to detect if my smartphone can communicate with my smartwatch.

If I add this line to my code:

```
NodeApi.GetConnectedNodesResult nodes = Wearable.NodeApi.getConnectedNodes(mApiClient).await();
```

when I close my app it stops receiving Toast messages. I don't know why.

**My Service code:**

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    initGoogleApiClient();
    new Thread( new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            while(true) {
                    NodeApi.GetConnectedNodesResult nodes = Wearable.NodeApi.getConnectedNodes(mApiClient).await();
                    Message messageWithoutSignal= new Message();
                    messageWithoutSignal.arg1 = 1;
                    messages.sendMessage(messageWithoutSignal);
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(2000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }).start();
    return START_STICKY;
}

 Handler messages= new Handler(new Handler.Callback() {
    @Override
    public boolean handleMessage(Message msg) {
        if(msg.arg1==1)
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Doesn't have signal!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return false;
    }
});
```

Thanks.

Comment: pass context in your service and pass that context in toast.

Comment: How can I pass the context on my service?

Comment: `Service` can access context simply by `getApplicationContext()` afaik.

Comment: I still don't understand what is wrong with my code...

Comment: Have you tried catching a general Exception instead of InterruptedException to see if there is anything else being thrown? For best Service practice, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21798659/android-best-practice-for-a-periodic-service

Comment: @Samun Arin I tried now. It is not throwing exceptions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used a TimerTask and now it is working instead of Thread.sleep. http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/TimerTask.html